# How to write js functions server side in nextjs

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I am trying to fetch data server side first time if a page is reloaded. For this, I am using `getInitialProps` in page to get the data. Here is the code that I am trying

```
    Student.getInitialProps = async (ctx) => {
  
    try {
      const response = await axios({
        method: "get",
        url: `http://localhost:3333/teacher/student/getAllStudent`,
        headers: ctx?.req?.headers?.cookie ? { cookie: ctx.req.headers.cookie } : undefined,
        withCredentials: true,
      })
      console.log("my reso",response.data)
      return { data: response.data }
    } catch (error) {
      if (ctx.res) {
        console.log(error.message)
        ctx.res.writeHead(302, {
          Location: "/",
        })
        ctx.res.end()
      }
    }
  }
```

this code works perfectly, but I would like to use a function to avoid writing same code/config again and again. Here headers, full url etc all are repeating every pages. How can I write it somewhere and use it from all pages?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Just make a separate function

For example, your func ./lib/functions/fetchDataFromServer.js

```
const fetchDataFromServer = async (ctx) => {
    try {
        const response = await axios({
            method: "get",
            url: `http://localhost:3333/teacher/student/getAllStudent`,
            headers: ctx?.req?.headers?.cookie ? {
                cookie: ctx.req.headers.cookie
            } : undefined,
            withCredentials: true,
        })
        console.log("my reso", response.data)
        return {
            data: response.data
        }
    } catch (error) {
        if (ctx.res) {
            console.log(error.message)
            ctx.res.writeHead(302, {
                Location: "/",
            })
            ctx.res.end()
        }
    }
}

export default fetchDataFromServer
```

and your file at pages directory

```
import fetchDataFromServer from './lib/functions/fetchDataFromServer'

export async function getInitialProps(ctx) {
    return fetchDataFromServer(ctx)
}
```

Comment: I would like to keep this file somewhere and use that from all pages, where should I place this js file for `fetchDataFromServer ` function?

Comment: @HkmSadek where you want. Edited the answer for an example